# Cannot update an item in WPF datagrid, values are always the same

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

I have a datagrid and I am binding an observable collection to it

```
private void BindDG()
{
    ObservableCollection<Person> personList = new ObservableCollection<Person>(PersonXml.GetPersonList());
    dgPersons.ItemsSource = personList;
}
```

The person class is as follows :-

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string surname { get; set; }

    private int _age;
    public int age
    {
        get { return _age ; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _age)
            {
                _age = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("age");
            }
        }
    }

    private int _salary;
    public int salary
    {
        get { return _salary; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _salary)
            {
                _salary = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("salary");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }   
}
```

And the update method is as follows :-

```
private void Update_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var selPerson = (Person)dgPersons.SelectedItem;
    if (UpdatePerson(selPerson))
        BindDG();
}
```

I also implemented the `CellEditEnding` event handler to no avail

```
private void DgPersons_OnCellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid grid = (DataGrid)sender;
    grid.CommitEdit(DataGridEditingUnit.Row, true);
}
```

What am I doing wrong.  When I debug my application, the values for age and salary are never changing, always the same as they started initially.

Thanks for your help and time

Comment: Can you provide the XAML as well? What does `UpdatePerson` do?

Comment: This would be much easier to do if you were following [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) pattern.

Comment: Does it work if you Bind the property instead of Setting it?

Comment: Editing cells in a WPF datagrid works best if you use the built-in transaction features.  Try that for better results.  Also, the observable collection needs to be a public property!

Comment: @Gary how do you edit cells in the WPF datagrid?

Comment: Change your collection to a public property, and add the Xaml to your question and then we can have a look.

Comment: ObservableCollection provides notifications when items get added, removed, or when the whole list is refreshed. Therefore, if you just edit the property value of the inner item. The control will not update as no notification received. You need to raise property change of the list by yourself. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Dirty solution is in BindDG, first set the ItemsSource to null, then set to the list you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try using BindingList instead of ObservableCollection to aggregate items changes